# Big O complexity of algorithm with a nested for loop only running once

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have been debating with someone about the big O complexity of the following algorithm. We have a different understanding of the theory. Basically one of us thinks that this algo is automatically O(N^2) since there is a loop over N elements and another potential other loop over N elements inside the loop. The other one thinks that since the second loop over N will only ever be executed once, the complexity is O(N). Help!

Here is the algorithm in Python:

```
def get_indexes(numbers, sum):
    s = set(numbers)
    for n in numbers:
        if n >= sum:
            continue
        if (sum - n) in s:
            return [numbers.find(n), numbers.find(sum - n)]
    return []
```

Comment: What does `return [numbers.find(n), numbers.find(sum - n)]` mean? Speak to me like I don't know Python.  Because... I don't.

Comment: You may profit from reading our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844).

Comment: @David Richerby  It returns a list of two numbers. The first is the index of n in numbers. find(n) goes through numbers and return the index of the first element equal to n. Same afterwards for sum - n.

Answer (score 1):

Both of you are correct. The algorithm runs in time $O(n^2)$ (where $n$ is the size of `numbers`), and it also runs in time $O(n)$.

Big O is only an upper bound on the running time. The algorithm also runs in $O(n^3)$, in $O(n\log n)$, in $O(2^n)$, and in $O(f(n))$ for many other (in fact, infinitely many) functions $f(n)$.

Comment: In what context does it go higher than O(N)? the initial for is N, then (sum - n) in s    is   O(1) since it's a set, but times N because of the loop. So we have 2*N. Then there are the two find functions that will be executed at most once each. So we have maximum 4*N, which amounts to O(N). Am I understanding the theory wrong?

Comment: @Chuque Look up the definition of the big-O notation! You are thinking of Big-Theta notation.

Comment: O (x) basically means "not slower than x times a constant". Your algorithm is "not slower than n^12 times a constant", therefore by definition it is in O (n^12).